# Why is grapheme_extract not extracting anything for "\r\n"?

Tags: php

While debugging an endless loop in a function using `grapheme_extract` in a loop to escape strings for debug output, i observed that for the string `"\r\n"` no code point `$cp` is returned and the `$next` pointer isn't updated.
Is this a bug or a feature somewhere documented (wasn't able to find anything about it)?
Are there other strings known to be ignored by `grapheme_extract`?

Minimal test case:

```
$next = 0;
$cp = grapheme_extract("\r\n", 1, GRAPHEME_EXTR_MAXCHARS, 0, $next);
echo implode('_', [strlen($cp), $next]);
```

Result: `0_0`, expected: `1_1`

PHP: 7.3.9 & 7.2.22, x64, Linux
`grapheme_extract` recognized the first byte for all other tested non-empty strings (including `"\0"`, `"\r\r"`, and `"\n\n"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled around some more and came to the conclusion, that `grapheme_extract` indeed has not been designed for what i tried to use it for.
Giving `GRAPHEME_EXTR_MAXCHARS` changes the granularity of the output string for length limiting only.
Extraction granularity always is a grapheme cluster *as present in the input string*.
 The two code points in `"\r\n"` would be valid clusters on their own but are treated as a single unit for extraction because they appear together in the input string and therefore form a single cluster by Unicode grapheme cluster separation rules.

Fixed minimal test case:

```
$next = 0;
$cp = mb_substr("\r\n", $next++, 1, 'UTF-8');
echo implode('_', [strlen($cp), $next]);
```

Result: `1_1` as expected